# Blazor wasm navigation

Tags: navigation, blazor, single-page-application, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

Can I use `@onclick='_ => NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/path/to/page")'` and still access to copy link address, when I open element's context menu(right-click on element in UI)?

Comment: No, and why would you do that?

Comment: I want to give user ability to copy link address of a text link

Comment: I meant why would you not use an anchor tag - the way web is supposed to be

Comment: An element that navigates should be an anchor `<a>` not some other element with an `onclick`

Comment: Thanks but I knew that I just wanted to know if there is a way to do it for other elements

Comment: https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet7/navigating-205577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you use NavigationManager to navigate, then the URL is hidden from the user.